# Insert the data of particular column in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table named as T1 with few columns. Out of these columns, one column name is `INSERT_DATE` and its datatype is `TIMESTAMP(3)`. I want to update the `INSERT_DATE` column with data `"ABC"` in all rows.

```
CREATE TABLE T1(NAME VARCHAR2(5), INSERT_DATE TIMESTAMP(3));

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('NAVIN',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('KAVIN',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('TAVIN',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

I have queried in oracle like

```
UPDATE T1
SET INSERT_DATE = 'ABC';
COMMIT;
```

It is not getting updated. Is there anything I need to add a code.

Comment: You can't store the string `ABC` inside a timestamp column.  Don't do that.

Comment: Is there any conversion needed in a code?

Comment: So what do you think can be converted from abc to timestamp? Abc is string. What is your expectation? What is time at your place? Have you ever answered, it's abc. Nope.

Comment: Do I need to change the datatype of INSERT_DATE column to varchar2(42)? or Is there any way other than this...If not, thanks for your help. I got your point

Comment: Why do you want to do this? A string such as "ABC" isn't anything like a timestamp. It seems illogical to want to store "ABC" in a column called `insert_date`, which you would think would store the date and time the row was inserted!